# Google Apps Script: Type Error Onform Submit

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to google apps script and i have issues with my macro script and require some help / advice. I am using google apps script btw.

TLDR version:
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined that happens and i was wondering how to resolve and troubleshoot it, also appreciate any feedback or advice that you guys might have.

Detailed version:
I have a google spreadsheet linked 3 different forms called form 2, 3, 4. As per usual, when a form is submitted, the data is populated into the individual-linked sheets. (let's call them sheets 2,3,4 respectively)
Now, the purpose for spreadsheet 3 and 4 is to collate and track movement and submission of customer's orders via the usage of timestamps. For each order, it could contain multiple serial numbers, each serial number representing an unique item in their order.
(For example, Mike's order is order number : ORDER-001, his order contains 3 serial numbers, LPN-001 ,LPN-002 and LPN-003, which in turn represents Milk and Cereal and Coffee)

When ORDER-001 is retrieved from the warehouse, the form 3 is submitted to indicate Mike's order has been taken out of the warehouse and sent to the supermarket.

Now, when he submits his order into Form 3, during the form submission, he might list the items in a single row). When the data is sent to the spreadsheet 3, it comes in the form of a list of serial numbers(LPN) in a single cell. What my script does is on the submission of order to Form 3, there is a trigger, the data submitted to spreadsheet 3 is populated on another spreadsheet called Form 3 - (Individual) , to split the rows properly.

(Actual example can see sheet itself)

Eg. Spreadsheet 3

|**Name**|***Order no.***___|________LPN no. _____________*|**timestamp***|
| Mike  | ORDER-001 | LPN-001,LPN-002,LPN-003 |29/11/21 10:30|

Eg. Spreadsheet 3-(Individual)

|**Name*|*Order no.*|***LPN no.****|**timestamp**_|

| Mike  |ORDER-001| LPN-001|29/11/21 10:30|

| Mike  |ORDER-001| LPN-002|29/11/21 10:30|

| Mike  |ORDER-001| LPN-003|29/11/21 10:30|

Form 4 is form is used by the supermarket manager. The manager receives the Order number ORDER-001, and has to go and retrieve the goods to prepare to deliver and outbound to the customer. Before outbounding the good, he has to fill form 4 to indicate that he has went to retrieve the order package. Similar to form 3, during the submission of the form, the LPNs are not in individual rows. There is a trigger set to this and a separate Spreadsheet known as " 4 - Outbounding (LPN Deactivation)" to split into individual rows.

For Spreadsheet "3 - LPN Movement Form" and it's 2nd spreadsheet "3 - LPN Movement (Individual)", it is running smoothly and no data errors.
However the majority of errors happens during form 4. For Spreadsheet 4-(Individual), the TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined appears and I don't know how to resolve it. For the trigger during onformsubmit, the data in spreadsheet 4-2 is sometimes populated and there are always random missing numbers. (eg missing random LPN-002 for Mike's order)

Here' my sample code:

```
// When a form is submitted, this script gets activated
// It will activate the correct function for the form that is submitted
// There are forms that will not activate the script
function formSubmit(e){
  Logger.log(e.range.getSheet().getName());
  switch(e.range.getSheet().getName()){
    case "3 - LPN Movement Form":
      onLPNMovementFormSubmit(e);
      break;
    case "4 - Outbounding Form":
      onGoodsOutboundingFormSubmit(e);
      break;

  }
}


//data processing functions that support the individual forms
var wms = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1097mFk6BTfopXwZ5fSX3h0YpLzaW2xs7YILwck4-6HA/');


var lpnDeactivationSheet = wms.getSheetByName("4 - Outbounding (LPN Deactivation)");
var lpnMovementSheet = wms.getSheetByName("3 - LPN Movement (Individual)");

function insertRowWithValues(inputSheet , dataArray){    
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(lpnDeactivationSheet);
  inputSheet.insertRows(2, 1);//shift all rows down by one from row 2
  inputSheet.getRange(2,1,1,dataArray.length)//(start row, start col  umn, number of rows, number of columns
    .setValues([dataArray]);
}

function splitLines(inputText){  
  return inputText.split(/\r?\n/);
}



function onLPNMovementFormSubmit(event) {  
  var form = event.namedValues;

  lpnList = splitLines(form['License Plate Number (LPN)'][0]);

  for (key in lpnList){      
    insertRowWithValues(lpnMovementSheet, 
      [lpnList[key],
      form['Origin Location ID'],
      form['Destination Location ID'],
      form['Email address'],
      form['Timestamp']]);
  }
}


function onGoodsOutboundingFormSubmit(event) {  
  var formTwo = event.namedValues;

  lpnListTwo = splitLines(formTwo['License Plate Number (LPN)'][0]);
  
  for (key in lpnListTwo){
    insertRowWithValues(lpnDeactivationSheet, 
      [lpnList[key],
      formTwo['Outbound Request ID'],
      formTwo['PO Number'],
      formTwo['Goods Condition'],
      formTwo['Goods Condition Remarks'],
      formTwo['Email address'],
      formTwo['Timestamp']]);
  }
}
```

Any advice / help ?Thanks in advance !!!!!!
Link:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1097mFk6BTfopXwZ5fSX3h0YpLzaW2xs7YILwck4-6HA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In your script, where does the error of `TLDR version: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined that happens and i was wondering how to resolve and troubleshoot it, also appreciate any feedback or advice that you guys might have.` occurs?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, it occurs only in the function : onGoodsOutboundingFormSubmit.  The trigger was formSubmit. I also start to recieve the error message ReferenceError: lpnList is not defined for the same function.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, it seems that `lpnList` is not declared. I think that this is the reason for your issue. Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, for example, when you modify `lpnList` to `lpnListTwo`, is that the result you expect?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for replying, was busy the last month.  I dont think it solves an issue, and currently i think the script is also facing another issue and i think i would start a totally new script instead. I'll post the the new script on another question instead of lumping it here.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `I dont think it solves an issue`, I think that the reason of this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would like to study more. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.